# Continuous recording in smallest file size. AudioRecord or MediaRecorder?

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder, recording, audiotrack

I am developing an Android application. In this app, 2 users talk to each other. At the side of 1st user, the app records using AudioRecord and sends recorded files to the server. At the other side, the app will download these files and play them using AudioTrack. This process is continuous; which means I keep recording and sending while the user is still talking. Everything is working fine but I have a problem with the size of the files to upload. I did not find a way to control the size of the recorded files. The whole problem can be solved if I can find a way to tell the audioRecord to use for example: setAudioSamplingRate(low), set lowAudioEncodingBitRate(low), setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.THREE_GPP), setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB).

I know we can use these with MediaRecorder, but I have to use AudioRecord because I want to analyze the sound before sending it.

Here, we have 2 things:
i) either to use MediaRecorder instead of AudioRecord (but can we keep recording in continuous way so that no sound will be lost?)
ii) or we find a way to tell AudioRecord to use the low-resolution settings

I don't care about the quality of the sound, I want the cheapest in terms of file size.
Find below my code:

Recording

```
int frequency = 11025;
int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);
DataOutputStream dos = getDOS();

int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++) dos.writeShort(enc(buffer[i]));

//Upload file to the server
```

---

Playing

```
//download from server, then ...

int intSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(11025, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT); 
final AudioTrack aud = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 11025, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, intSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

short[] arr = SoundFile2Array(f1);
aud.write(arr, 0, (int)(arr.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to minimize data traffic.

I think one of the issues is that PCM is basically uncompressed audio, which is not great for minimizing bandwidth used. What I think you want to do is use MediaCodec to create an encoder, perhaps for something like amr/nb. Then feed the audio frames into the encoder by queuing input buffers and upload the encoded data by dequeueing output buffers.